# How to repeat last stroke in Blender's sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

Is there in Blender, in Sculpt Mode, something like in the Zbrush function called `Repeat last stroke`?
This option repeats last sculpt stroke as many times as I press a key.

Comment: This is not yet possible. It might never become be possible, because it's a sort of weird paradigm; How does this work exactly, does it depend on the view? It doesn't seem too helpful.

Comment: https://youtu.be/joDoCiFC4Ig?t=23969 here is demo of repeat function in zbrush
I guess it works some how recording x and y movements and then re-projecting that movement again. This would be nice indeed. But also some kind of procedural strokes to control displacement would be nice - like the bloom editor https://thebloomapp.com/features/ it was is? procedural graphics app - like affinity designer or illustrator, vector app. Also having this kind of procedural texturing would be good for generating animations - textured lego faces with procedural lines and shapes - like greasepencil but projec